# 0xC0000005 error using PyQt5 and paho-mqtt in Python3

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, mqtt

I have the following code which should get data via MQTT and display it on text labels:

```
import sys, design, random
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt_client

broker = 'broker.emqx.io'
port = 1883
topic = 'topic/testproject'
# generate client ID with pub prefix randomly
client_id = f'python-mqtt-{random.randint(0, 100)}'


def other_function(label):
    label.setText("Work pls")


class App(QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        super().setupUi(self)

        self.client = self.connect_mqtt()
        self.client.on_message = self.on_message
        self.client.subscribe(topic)
        self.client.loop_start()

    def on_message(self, client, userdata, msg):
        self.nv.setText("a")

    @staticmethod
    def connect_mqtt() -> mqtt_client:
        def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
            if rc == 0:
                print("Connected to MQTT Broker!")
            else:
                print("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc)

        client = mqtt_client.Client(client_id)
        client.on_connect = on_connect
        client.connect(broker, port)
        return client


if __name__ == '__main__':
    qt = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = App()
    app.show()
    qt.exec_()
```

Which shows the app window, but then immediately crashes.

If I change the method on_message to a static method, then the program doesn't crash and is able to print received data, but then I can't access the labels from the class App and display the data I receive. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I don't know how that module works, but I strongly believe that it uses threading, meaning that you cannot directly access the UI from there (widgets are not thread safe). You should probably implement a QThread subclass with custom signals.

Comment: Paho callbacks run on the client's network loop thread